# How to reproduce the result of perturbative $\phi^4$ from exact RG

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I am studying Exact RG and I have a question.

I think, it should be possible to reproduce the flow equation of $\lambda_4$ term in perturbative RG, from exact RG.
However, from Peskin, equation of $\lambda_4$ is like
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\lambda_4}{dt} \sim \lambda_4^2
\end{equation}
when I use $t=\log \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is the cutoff, and the Polchinski equation is like
\begin{equation}
\frac{d S_{I,\Lambda}}{d t} \sim -\frac{1}{2} \left[\left(\frac{\delta S_{I,\Lambda}}{\delta \phi}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\delta^2 S_{I,\Lambda}}{\delta \phi^2}\right) \right],
\end{equation}
according to "An Introduction to Exact RG" from Sathiapalan.
However, if I equate the terms in Polchinski equation of order $\phi^4$, naively I won't get terms like $\lambda_4^2$. Does anyone know what I messed up?

Comment: Which page/equation in P&S?

Comment: Page 404 for Wilsonian RG and Page 422 for Stueckelberg-Petermann (ordinary) renormalization. It is natural that it becomes the order of \lambda^2 from diagrammatical consideration.

Comment: I am sorry to comment on my own question, but this paper seems to derive beta function of $\lambda_4$, so I will take a look into it.
Tim R Morris, "The Exact Renormalization Group and Approximate Solutions"